# Calculating expectation of the number of balls that were not taken out of a box

Tags: probability

Given a box with 10 balls numbered 1 to 10, each time we take out one ball randomly and return it back to the box. The process stops the first time we take out a ball with the number 1.
We need to calculate the expected value of the number of balls that were not taken out of the box.

I tried the following:
$X$ -  The number of balls that were not taken out of the box.
$X_i$ - the ball numbered $i$ was not taken out of the box.
$N\sim Geo(\frac{1}{10})$ - The number of trials until a ball numbered 1 was taken out.
$P(X_i = 1) = (\frac{8}{10})^N$
$X=\sum_2^{10}X_i$

Then use law of total expectation and transformation:
$E(X)=E(E(X|N))=E(E(\sum_2^{10}X_i|N))=9E((\frac{8}{10})^N)$
$=9\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{8}{10})^n\cdot(\frac{9}{10})^{n-1}\cdot(\frac{1}{10})^1$

But the answer is not right, I'd appreciate if you could help me understand what's wrong here

Comment: Your notation is not clear.  What is $X_i$?

Comment: For the problem:  use linearity.  Set an indicator variable for each box (other than $1$), according to whether it appears before $1$ or not.

Comment: I have added an addendum for drawing with replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $N$ is not a fixed number.
$$P(X_i=1)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(N=m)P(X_i=1|N=m)$$
On the other hand, consider just those times that balls $1$ and $i$ are chosen.  It is equally likely the first from that set is $1$, or $i$.  So $P(X_i=1)=1/2$

Comment: Is it true that: $P(X_i =1) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\frac{8}{10})^{m-1}\cdot (\frac{9}{10})^{m-1}\cdot (\frac{1}{10})^1$ ? Because it is not equal 0.5

Comment: What is the $(9/10)^{m-1}$ factor for?

Comment: $(\frac{9}{10})^{m-1}\cdot (\frac{1}{10}) $ is for $P(N=m) $ and N is geometric

Comment: Oh.  Given that $N=m$, all the previous digits are not 1, so the chance of $i$ missing out too is $(8/9)^{m-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator r.v. that is equal to $1$ if a number (other than $1$) was **not** taken out before $1$, and zero otherwise.

Then by symmetry, $P(X_i) = \frac12$

Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus

$\Bbb E[X_i] = \frac12$

and by linearity of expectation,
which operates even if the variables are not independent,

$\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[X_2] + \Bbb E[X3] + ... \Bbb E[X_9] = 9\times \frac12 = 4.5$

---

### *Addendum*

If ball is replaced each time after drawing, I'll compute expected number of balls drawn out until **1** drawn out, and the answer will then be $10 - \Bbb E[Y]$

$\displaylines{\Bbb E[Y =1] = 1*0.9^0*0.1,\\  
\Bbb E[Y=2] = 2*0.9^1*0.1,\\ 
 \Bbb E[Y=3] = 3*0.9^2*0.1\;\; and \;so\; on}$

Thus $$\Bbb E[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^{10} k*0.9^{k-1}/10 \approx 3.0264$$

thus $\Bbb E[X] \approx 6.9736  $

Comment: I did not really understand why $P(X_i) = \frac12$, can you explain?

Comment: If you take any two numbers A and B in a line of numbers,  by symmetry, A is as likely to be before B as after it.

Comment: Got it, can you explain why my way is not right though?

Comment: Every time you draw a ball, the number of balls changes. So you can't model it as N ~Geo(1/10)

Comment: Just consider, P(first ball is $1) = \frac1{10}$. P(second ball is $1)= \frac9{10}\frac19 = \frac1{10}$, and so on, it always remains $\frac1{10}$, so $\Bbb E[X] = \frac1{10}(9+8+7+....+0)$

Comment: But every time we draw a ball we return it back into the box so the number of balls remains the same no?

Comment: Then it becomes a different question altogether. I have added an addendum to address that